# mysql_php_insert query from inside a while

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to make a like button, but i can't send proper query from a loop.
this is my sample code:

```
$supql="SELECT * FROM `tbl_users_posts`";
$rez=mysqli_query($conn,$supql);
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rez)){
$psid=$row['id'];
echo $row['post']."<br>";

$squlk="SELECT uid FROM t_plik WHERE pid='$psid' AND uid='$uid'";
    $msqs=mysqli_query($conn,$squlk);
    $asnu=mysqli_num_rows($msqs);

if($asnu==0){?>
<a href="" class="like" id="<?php echo $psid;?>"> like</a>
<?php }else{ ?>
    <a href="" class="unlike" id="<?php echo $psid;?>"> unlike</a>
<?php }
}
```

i try send this query:

```
if(isset($_POST['liked'])){
    $pstid=$_POST['postid'];
    $inslik="INSERT INTO t_plik (pid,uid)VALUES('$pstid','$uid') ";
    mysqli_query($conn,$inslik);
}
```

with this jquery code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    //when click on like
    $('.like').click(function(){
        var postid = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            url:'test.php',
            type:'post',
            async: false,
            data:{
                'liked': 1,
                'postid':postid
            },
            success:function(){

            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

but every time when i click like button i can send query for last post id. how can i affect other postids inside the while?
thanks

Comment: You need to make loop for each '.like' element then you can use above code.

Comment: like is in the while loop

Comment: can you please differentiate between the php script that processes ajax from the php script where you render the query result?

Comment: also remove `async: false,`

Comment: ajax script is in the end of the script

Comment: i try move the query in while loop and out side the loop.inside the loop insert multy query. out side just last one